# How to check what Scanf recieved?

Tags: c, scanf

Program shouldallow two different patterns and calculate different things depending on what was recieved from the user.
Lets say that the patterns are:

> x <12;23>

or

> <12;23>

If 'x' was included, program would convert the interval to binary, if not, it would convert it to duodecimal.
But how to chceck if user included that?

I have a code looking for the 'x'

```
    int a;
    int b;
    char x;
    char one;
    char dot;
    char two;

  if((scanf(" %c %c %ld %c %ld %c", &x,&one,&a,&dot,&b, &two)!=6)||(x!='x')||(one!='<')||(dot!=';')||(two!='>')){
      printf("Wrong input");
  }
  else{
      /*Convert to binary*/
  }
```

EDIT: Changed numbers in intervals to make it easier to understand

Comment: How is ` <2;3>` a duodecimal representation of a number? How to convert "interval" into "binary"? You mean just convert the "2" and "3" into numbers?

Comment: I see that I gave wrong numbers to represent this question. I would convert each number from the interval. In this case I would convert only 2 and 3 to binary. In <10;20> I would convert 10,11,12,13,14......19,20.

Comment: I don't get this part. Binary has only 0 and 1, so you want to convert 2 and 3 into 10 and 11, it's a different question on how to convert a number into it's binary representation. And still, what do you want to convert into duodecimal?

Comment: The problem is, that if user inputs "x <12;30>" it should convert all those numbers into binary. But if he only inputs "<12;30>" without the "x" it should convert those numbers to duodecimal. But I don't know how to check if the X is included or not from juts one single input

Comment: `binary` and `duodecimal` are number representations. The user inputs the values in representation of base 10, anyway? And you want to print the numbers in binary representation in case of x is present and you want to print the number using doedecimal representation in case x is not present?

Comment: I'm confused, by the comments even more than the question itself... the question *seems* to be about `scanf()`, but from the comments it seems more like a [xy problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: Don't use `scanf`.  Read the data, and parse it.

Answer (score 1):

Just specify the format in scanf.

```
int read_input(int *a, int *b)
{
   int ret;
   ret = scanf(" x <%d;%d>", a, b)
   if (ret < 0) return -__LINE__;
   if (ret == 2) {
       return 1;
   }
   ret = scanf(" <%d;%d>", a, b);
   if (ret < 0) return -__LINE__;
   if (ret == 2) {
       return 2;
   }
   return -__LINE__;
}

int main() {
   int a, b;
   while(1) {
       int ret = read_input(&a, &b);
       if (ret < 0) {
          printf("wrong input!\n");
       } else {
          printf("%s format - %d %d\n", ret == 1 ? "first" : "second", a, b);
       }
   }
}
```

The first scanf will want to read `x` on the beginning of the line. If it doesn't find it, it will convert zero numbers and return zero. We can then proceed to the second scanf with the second format and check for it.